# I am looking for a way to rotate a sprite in direction of drag

Tags: javascript, rotation, drag, phaser-framework

How can I rotate a sprite in the direction of drag while being draged? I dont want the sprite rotate towards the input pointer (toch,mouse) if its not pixel perfect clicked. Also I would like to still be able to use physics on the sprite using the phaser framework.

```
update: function() {
    this.game.physics.arcade.collide(this.car, this.block);
   // this.game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.car, this.traffic, this.bremsen);
/*if(this.car.input.pixelPerfectOver=true){

  this.angleBetweenPoints();
};*/
//this.car.rotate=this.car.angle;
//game.debug.spriteInputInfo(this.car, 32, 32);
  },

  angleBetweenPoints: function (point1, point2) {
this._dragPoint = new Phaser.Point(this.car.x, this.car.y);

Phaser.Math.angleBetween(this.car.x, 
                  this.car.y, game.input.activePointer.x,game.input.activePointer.y);

this.car.angle= Phaser.Math.angleBetween(this.game.input.activePointer.x, 
                  this.game.input.activePointer.y, this._dragPoint.x,this._dragPoint.y);

},


   animatecar: function(sprite, event) {



if ((this.angleBetweenPoints(this.car.y, this.game.input.activePointer.y)) > 0.1) {

    console.log(this.angleBetweenPoints(this.car.y, game.input.y));
  }
      this.car.input.enableDrag();

  },
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of your tries? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i pasted it above but i did discard some versions of it already i basicaly need some mix from [this](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/sprite-rotation) and [this](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/angle-to-pointer) but only if the sprite is draged

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning rotation to the sprite directly, but when using physics bodies, you should change rotation on the body:

```
this.car.body.rotation = ...   // For radians
this.car.body.angle = ...   // For degrees
```